# move items within a listbox that filled from list of keyvaluepair

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a list of integers.5 items max.These 5 integers shows 5 indexes of listbox items.I want to move this items in the first 5 places of this listbox.This listbox is filled from a list with this code

```
 uList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(item.Id, item.Name));
 listBoxHome.DataSource = uList;
 listBoxHome.DisplayMember = "Value";
 listBoxHome.ValueMember = "Key";
```

indexes is the list of integers refer to index of items.

```
 game.listBoxHome.BeginUpdate();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            foreach (int PlayingInd in indexes)
            {
                HomeList.Insert(i, HomeList[PlayingInd]);
                HomeList.RemoveAt(PlayingInd);

            }
        }
        game.listBoxHome.DataSource = HomeList;
        game.listBoxHome.DisplayMember = "Value";
        game.listBoxHome.ValueMember = "Key";
        game.listBoxHome.EndUpdate();
```

I use this code to one form:

```
  public void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {      
  Sub sub = new Sub();   
  foreach (ListItem item in listBox2.Items)
                {
                    uList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(item.Id, item.Name));

                }
                sub.HomeList = uList;
  }
```

And in the other form:

```
    private BindingList<KeyValuePair<int, string>> Homelist;
    public BindingList<KeyValuePair<int, string>> GetHomelist
    {
        get { return Homelist; }
        set { Homelist = value; }            
    }        
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            BindingList<int> indexes = new BindingList<int>();
            foreach (int indexChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices)
            {
                indexes.Add(indexChecked);
            }
            Game game = new Game();


            foreach (int PlayingInd in indexes)
            {
                Homelist.Insert(0, Homelist[PlayingInd]);
                Homelist.RemoveAt(PlayingInd + 1);
                }
            game.GetHomelist = Homelist;

            this.Close();
        }
```

solved

Comment: As long your listbox is bound to a datasource you will have to manipulate the datasource, not the listbox to change the order, I think.

Comment: How can get the KeyValuePair of a specific index place in a list?

Comment: You can Remove() or RemoveAt() and Insert() and also RemoveRange()  and InsertRange() in a List<> to change the order of its elements.

Comment: yes.I use it but the list is empty and gives me error.I have the problem to copy a list from a form to another.How can pass a list to another form?

Comment: Um, that sounds like a totally different problem, right? to pass data beteween form or to share it you will always need a reference to the other form or its filed(s). Many ways to achieve this and dozends of answered questions here in SO..